# Apple Photos "paused" synching since update to High Sierra

Tags: macos, photos, data-synchronization, high-sierra

Since updating to High Sierra, Apple Photos has stopped syncing photos, claiming that I'm "not connected to the Internet":

[image]

So no recent photos are available on my Mac, and there's apparently nothing I can do about it.

What's the point of this behavior and how do I fix it?

---

(Meanwhile, since an update to iOS 11.1.1 — actually a bricking "update" — Photos on iOS are [again way behind what they should be](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/299494/4395).)

Comment: Is this the same account you are struggling with on iOS? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/299494/photos-on-ios-11-re-uploading-entire-library-to-icloud What geographic region are you and is your network filtered / run through Zscaler or equivalent “proxy / security / man-in-the-middle recording” perhaps?